Mismatch in Vertex Data Between GLSL Compute Shader and C# OpenGL Buffer Read
I am working on a C# script that uses a compute shader to generate a file containing a list of vertices and indices representing an icosphere. I use the compute shader to compute vertex positions and the indices, which I then read back in C# using OpenTK. However, the vertex data I retrieve in C# does not match the expected output defined in the GLSL shader. For testing I simplified the
compute shader to just define and output some vertices.
Here is the C# script:
using OpenTK.Mathematics;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4;
using OpenTK.Windowing.Desktop;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using OpenTK.Windowing.GraphicsLibraryFramework;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float diameter = 5000f;
        string computeShaderFilePath = @"C:\Users\leona\Desktop\Sphere_Shader.compute";
        string outputFilePath = @"C:\Users\leona\Desktop\Sphere_3.bin";

        IcoSphereCreator creator = new IcoSphereCreator();
        creator.Create(diameter, computeShaderFilePath, outputFilePath);
    }
}

public class IcoSphereCreator
{
    private int computeShaderProgram;
    private int verticesBuffer;
    private int indicesBuffer;
    private int verticesCount = 12; // 12 initial vertices
    private int indicesCount = 60; // 60 initial indices (20 triangles x 3 vertices)
    private List<Vector3> vertices = new List<Vector3>();
    private List<int> indices = new List<int>();

    public void Create(float diameter, string computeShaderFilePath, string outputFilePath)
    {
        var gameWindowSettings = new GameWindowSettings();
        var nativeWindowSettings = new NativeWindowSettings();
        using (var window = new GameWindow(gameWindowSettings, nativeWindowSettings))
        {
            GL.LoadBindings(new GLFWBindingsContext());

            LoadComputeShader(computeShaderFilePath);
            InitializeBuffers();
            GenerateAndDispatchCompute();
            ReadBuffers(diameter);
            SaveMeshToFile(outputFilePath);

            Console.WriteLine("IcoSphere creation completed.");
        }
    }

    private void LoadComputeShader(string filePath)
    {
        string shaderSource = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        int shader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.ComputeShader);
        GL.ShaderSource(shader, shaderSource);
        GL.CompileShader(shader);

        GL.GetShader(shader, ShaderParameter.CompileStatus, out int compiled);
        if (compiled != (int)All.True)
        {
            string infoLog = GL.GetShaderInfoLog(shader);
            Console.WriteLine($"Error compiling shader: {infoLog}");
            return;
        }

        computeShaderProgram = GL.CreateProgram();
        GL.AttachShader(computeShaderProgram, shader);
        GL.LinkProgram(computeShaderProgram);

        GL.GetProgram(computeShaderProgram, GetProgramParameterName.LinkStatus, out int linkStatus);
        if (linkStatus != 1)
        {
            string log = GL.GetProgramInfoLog(computeShaderProgram);
            Console.WriteLine($"Shader program linking failed: {log}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Shader program compiled and linked successfully.");
        }

        GL.DetachShader(computeShaderProgram, shader);
        GL.DeleteShader(shader);
    }


    private void InitializeBuffers()
    {
        GL.CreateBuffers(1, out verticesBuffer);
        GL.NamedBufferStorage(verticesBuffer, verticesCount * 3 * sizeof(float), IntPtr.Zero, BufferStorageFlags.DynamicStorageBit);
        GL.BindBufferBase(BufferRangeTarget.ShaderStorageBuffer, 0, verticesBuffer);

        GL.CreateBuffers(1, out indicesBuffer);
        GL.NamedBufferStorage(indicesBuffer, indicesCount * sizeof(int), IntPtr.Zero, BufferStorageFlags.DynamicStorageBit);
        GL.BindBufferBase(BufferRangeTarget.ShaderStorageBuffer, 1, indicesBuffer);
    }


    private void GenerateAndDispatchCompute()
    {
        GL.UseProgram(computeShaderProgram);
        int numGroups = (verticesCount + 63) / 64; 
        GL.DispatchCompute(numGroups, 1, 1);
        GL.MemoryBarrier(MemoryBarrierFlags.VertexAttribArrayBarrierBit);

        CheckOpenGLError("DispatchCompute");
    }

    private void ReadBuffers(float diameter)
    {
        
        float[] verticesData = new float[verticesCount * 3];
        int[] indicesData = new int[indicesCount];

        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ShaderStorageBuffer, verticesBuffer);
        GL.GetBufferSubData(BufferTarget.ShaderStorageBuffer, IntPtr.Zero, verticesData.Length * sizeof(float), verticesData);

        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ShaderStorageBuffer, indicesBuffer);
        GL.GetBufferSubData(BufferTarget.ShaderStorageBuffer, IntPtr.Zero, indicesData.Length * sizeof(int), indicesData);

        vertices.Clear();
        indices.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine("Vertices Data:");
        for (int i = 0; i < verticesData.Length; i += 3)
        {
            Vector3 vertex = new Vector3(verticesData[i], verticesData[i + 1], verticesData[i + 2]);
            vertices.Add(vertex);
            Console.WriteLine($"Vertex {i / 3}: ({vertex.X:F3}, {vertex.Y:F3}, {vertex.Z:F3})");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Indices Data:");
        for (int i = 0; i < indicesData.Length; i++)
        {
            indices.Add(indicesData[i]);
            Console.WriteLine($"Index {i}: {indicesData[i]}");
        }
    }



    private void SaveMeshToFile(string filename)
    {
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
        {
            // Write the number of vertices
            writer.Write(vertices.Count);

            // Write each vertex component as a float
            foreach (Vector3 vertex in vertices)
            {
                writer.Write(vertex.X);
                writer.Write(vertex.Y);
                writer.Write(vertex.Z);
            }

            // Write the number of indices
            writer.Write(indices.Count);

            // Write each index as an int
            foreach (int index in indices)
            {
                writer.Write(index);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Mesh file saved successfully.");
    }


    private void CheckOpenGLError(string operation)
    {
        OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4.ErrorCode errorCode = GL.GetError();
        if (errorCode != OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4.ErrorCode.NoError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"OpenGL error during operation '{operation}': {errorCode}");
        }
    }
}

And here is the compute shader:
#version 450

layout(local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;

layout(std430, binding = 0) buffer OutputVerticesBuffer {
    vec3 outputVertices[]; // Correctly using the declared buffer name
};

void main() {
    // Set the vertices directly
    outputVertices[0] = vec3(-1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    outputVertices[1] = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    outputVertices[2] = vec3(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0);
    outputVertices[3] = vec3(1.0, -1.0, 0.0);
    outputVertices[4] = vec3(0.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    outputVertices[5] = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    outputVertices[6] = vec3(0.0, -1.0, -1.0);
    outputVertices[7] = vec3(0.0, 1.0, -1.0);
    outputVertices[8] = vec3(1.0, 0.0, -1.0);
    outputVertices[9] = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    outputVertices[10] = vec3(-1.0, 0.0, -1.0);
    outputVertices[11] = vec3(-1.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    // Ensure that all writes to buffer are completed before ending the shader
    memoryBarrierShared();
    barrier();
}

From the debug check I set after reading the buffers I get these vertices that are different from what I specified in the compute shader:
Vertices Data:
Vertex 0: (-1,000, 1,000, 0,000)
Vertex 1: (0,000, 1,000, 1,000)
Vertex 2: (0,000, 0,000, -1,000)
Vertex 3: (-1,000, 0,000, 0,000)
Vertex 4: (1,000, -1,000, 0,000)
Vertex 5: (0,000, 0,000, -1,000)
Vertex 6: (1,000, 0,000, 0,000)
Vertex 7: (1,000, 1,000, 0,000)
Vertex 8: (0,000, -1,000, -1,000)
Vertex 9: (0,000, 0,000, 1,000)
Vertex 10: (-1,000, 0,000, 1,000)
Vertex 11: (0,000, -1,000, 0,000)

I am not receiving any errors. Could there be an issue with how the buffer is declared or bound in either GLSL or C#?
